# Is there a tool like valgrind memcheck for Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm a teacher of a beginning C programming class. Some of my students use Macs for their development. I recommend to them to use Xcode with clang and lldb, since it has the best support on their platform. (On other platforms I recommend Eclipse and gcc, since gcc has better support for the C language than Microsoft's compiler.) Since we're introducing pointers as part of the course, it would be useful to have a tool like valgrind's memcheck that will check for the use of uninitialized memory. Is there such a tool that can be used with Xcode? The sanitizer tools referred by https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early don't explicitly mention checking for the use of uninitialized values.

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431697